# CSS opaque background IE6 - IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, background, internet-explorer-6

i was using a RGBA background, but it was not working in IE6. I found a way to sort this online.

```
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #87C4CF;
    background: rgba(135, 196, 207, 0.7);
    background:rgb(135,196,207);
    background: transparent\9;
    background:rgba(135,196,207,0.7);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#b287C4CF,endColorstr=#b287C4CF);
    zoom: 1;
}
table:nth-child(n) {
    filter: none;
}
```

This works in IE6 but now the table does not display in IE 8. Works fine in every other browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a translucent background really going to make or break your layout?

1. For IE8, make a translucent 10px x 10px PNG in PhotoShop with the color and transparency you want and set it
   as the background image, repeating.
2. Give IE6 a solid background
   color
3. Everything else will support your rgba() background syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to better your life with ie